# Define a subset from another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a closed disc $D$ 
\begin{equation}
D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: (x-a)^{2}+ (y-b)^{2} \leq R^{2}   \}
\end{equation}
centred at the origin $(a,b)=(0,0)$ and with radius $R=15$ [m]. I have discretised the two-dimensional space $D$ to obtain a finite set of points $(x,y)$ using the polar coordinate system
\begin{equation}
x=r \cos \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=r \sin \theta
\end{equation}
with 
\begin{equation}
r \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 15 \} \ \mathrm{[m]}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\theta \in \pm \{0, 15, 30,\dots,180\} \ \mathrm{[deg]}
\end{equation}
I would like to be able to define a subset A which contains all of the points $(x,y)$ (i.e., the elements of $r$ and $\theta$) belonging to the set D which satisfy the condition $S>0$. Likewise, I would be able to define another set B which contains all of the points $(x,y)$ belonging to the set D which satisfy the condition $S=0$.

Am I correct in thinking that I first need to define indices for $r$ and $\theta$, e.g., $r_{i}, \ i \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 15 \}$? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is S in your notation?

Comment: Thank you for your reply - ensbana. If I may elaborate, I am conducting a numerical experiment using a mathematical model in which $x$ and $y$ are variables. The numerical experiement is being carried out for different values $(x,y)$ (by varying $r$ and $\theta$) to determine whether another variable $S$ is greater than zero, or equal to zero (it can only be one or the other). Essentially I am trying to define the two subsets $A$ and $B$ that encompass all of the elements in $r$ and $\theta$ for which $S>0$ and $S=0$, respectively.

Comment: ensbana - NB: $S$ is not explicitly dependent on $x$ and $y$ if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If S is not dependent on x and y, then how can you use S as the criterion to partition the set?

Comment: My apologies, I come from an Engineering background. $S$ is implicitly dependant on $x$ and $y$. I.e., varying $x$ and $y$ in my numerical experiment does cause a change in $S$.

Comment: Could you elaborate how S changes as x and y vary? It's hard to do anything further without knowing how S is related to the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88516/discussion-between-bob1986-and-ensbana).